# How to use [DllImport("")] in C#?

Tags: c#, process, dllimport

I found a lot of questions about it, but no one explains how I can use this.

I have this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;

public class WindowHandling
{
    public void ActivateTargetApplication(string processName, List<string> barcodesList)
    {
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr point);
        Process p = Process.Start("notepad++.exe");
        p.WaitForInputIdle();
        IntPtr h = p.MainWindowHandle;
        SetForegroundWindow(h);
        SendKeys.SendWait("k");
        IntPtr processFoundWindow = p.MainWindowHandle;
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to understand why it gives me an error on the `DllImport` line and on the `public static` line?

Does anyone have an idea, what can I do?
Thank you.

Comment: There are multiple issues in addition to what @vcsjones has mentioned. Do you have User32.dll where you are using this. And also check the place where you have written the [DllImport] statement.Its wrong place.

Comment: @PM. User32.dll is a pretty standard Win32 DLL that will always be in SysWow64 or System32, so there shouldn't be an issue with finding it. It might find the *wrong* one if there is another DLL with the same name that is "closer" in the search sequence, but that would bring disaster to most programs.

Comment: @vcsjones Oh ok, my bad. I was not aware.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can't declare an `extern` local method inside of a method, or any other method with an attribute. Move your DLL import into the class:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


public class WindowHandling
{
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr point);

    public void ActivateTargetApplication(string processName, List<string> barcodesList)
    {
        Process p = Process.Start("notepad++.exe");
        p.WaitForInputIdle();
        IntPtr h = p.MainWindowHandle;
        SetForegroundWindow(h);
        SendKeys.SendWait("k");
        IntPtr processFoundWindow = p.MainWindowHandle;
    }
}
```

Comment: You must also be using `System.Runtime.InteropServices` in Microsoft Visual Studio

Comment: You must also be using `System.Diagnostics`  in order to use the Process object

Answer (score 4):

Starting with C# 9, your syntax would be valid if you remove the `public` keyword from the `SetForegroundWindow` declaration:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;

public class WindowHandling
{
    public void ActivateTargetApplication(string processName, List<string> barcodesList)
    {
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr point);
        Process p = Process.Start("notepad++.exe");
        p.WaitForInputIdle();
        IntPtr h = p.MainWindowHandle;
        SetForegroundWindow(h);
        SendKeys.SendWait("k");
        IntPtr processFoundWindow = p.MainWindowHandle;
    }
}
```

In C# 9, local functions can have attributes, see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/local-function-attributes).