# ftrScanApi.dll reference could not be added

Tags: c#, dll, window

I am trying to add `ftrScanApi.dll` reference into my window application but it gives me error of:

> "A reference to ... dll could not be added. Please make sure that the
>   file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component."

I have tried all the help available online but couldn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't googled enough : double check [A reference to the dll could not be added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456758/a-reference-to-the-dll-could-not-be-added)

[I want a solution for this : Please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080447/i-want-a-solution-for-this-please-make-sure-that-the-file-is-accessible-and-th)

Basically it's not native dll that you can add in visual studio by "Add reference".

Try to use dllimport if you know methods for that dll
[How to use [DllImport("")] in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450783/how-to-use-dllimport-in-c)

Edit : 
Some more googling showed that dll was written with c++. You can find header file [here](http://read.pudn.com/downloads110/sourcecode/math/457634/FingerprintDemo/fingerprint/ftr%20scanner/ftrScanAPI.h__.htm) - this will help you to get methods/functions for that dll.

Comment: No.. i have googled too much, but when i contacted the companies technical team then they replied that "you can not add this dll directly as it is native dll", and then they provided me a different source code that i used later.