# Invoke C++ method on runtime from C# delegate

Tags: c#, c++, delegates

I am creating delegate in C#. C# solution is class library means using dll in different application.

In C# I want to invoke C++ method(method defined by another programmer), this methods need to call on runtime. For that I am using delegate, but I don't know how to use delegate in C# and how to store C++ function details for that delegate.

below one is the high level requirement :

1. Create C# DLL
2. Import that DLL into C++ application.
3. Call C# methods from C++ application code.
4. During step 3, while invoking C# methods for particular case I needs to call C++ method for that I am using delegate. Please let me know other best approach as well.

From above mentioned steps, till step # 3 I am able to code it. For that used one of solution mentioned in below link :

[How to call a C# library from Native C++ (using C++\CLI and IJW)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293888/how-to-call-a-c-sharp-library-from-native-c-using-c-cli-and-ijw)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use \[DllImport("")\] in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450783/how-to-use-dllimport-in-c)

Comment: Below on is high level logic i am working :

in C++

void onStartUp()
{
     //...................
}

in C#
class myDeleagte
{
public Action onStartUpDelegate;
if (request.contains("StartUp"))
{
   //Call C++ method stored in onStartUpDelegate Action variable.
}
}

Comment: https://xaviergeerinck.com/binding-cpp-with-dotnet-core